# how to write subquery in zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, join

I have a core query below which is working well on phpmyadmin

> SELECT `u`.`id`, `u`.`username`, `u`.`firstname`, `u`.`lastname`,
>   `u`.`email`, `amanager`.`id` AS `asid`, `amanager`.`pm_id`,
>   `amanager`.`scheme_id`, `amanager`.`created`, `amanager`.`changed`,
>   `amanager`.`status`, `p`.`scheme_name` AS `projectname`,
>   `roles`.`title` AS `role_name`, `ministry`.`ministry_name` FROM
>   `dbt_users` AS `u` LEFT JOIN `dbt_assign_manager` AS `amanager` ON
>   u.id = amanager.pm_id LEFT JOIN `dbt_scheme` AS `p` ON p.id
>   in(amanager.scheme_id) LEFT JOIN `dbt_roles` AS `roles` ON u.role =
>   roles.id LEFT JOIN `dbt_ministry` AS `ministry` ON p.ministry_id =
>   ministry.id WHERE (u.status = 1 and u.role in(4,6) and u.createdby = 7
>   ) or u.id in( select distinct ux.id from dbt_users as ux left outer
>   join dbt_assign_manager as ax on ux.id = ax.pm_id left outer join
>   dbt_scheme as sx on ax.scheme_id = sx.id left outer join dbt_ministry
>   as dx on dx.id= sx.ministry_id where dx.id = 81 )

which I need to convert into Zend framework sub query. I did first half of the query but I don't know how to write the sub query part
Below is the query which is written by me

```
$select->from(array('u' => 'dbt_users'),
array('firstname','lastname'))      ->joinLeft(array('amanager' => 'dbt_assign_manager'), 'u.id = amanager.pm_id',
array('id','pm_id','scheme_id','created','changed','status'))
        ->joinLeft(array('p' => 'dbt_scheme'), 'p.id
 in(amanager.scheme_id)', array('p.scheme_name as projectname'))
        ->joinLeft(array('roles' => 'dbt_roles'), 'u.role = roles.id',
 array('title as role_name'))       ->where('u.status = 1 and u.role
 in(4,6) and u.createdby=7')        ->where('u.id in( select distinct ux.id
 from dbt_users as ux left outer join dbt_assign_manager as ax on ux.id
 = ax.pm_id left outer join dbt_scheme as sx on ax.scheme_id = sx.id left outer join dbt_ministry as dx on dx.id= sx.ministry_id where
 dx.id = 81');
```

its give me the below error

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\dbt\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:248 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dbt\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dbt\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\dbt\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\dbt\index.php(66): Zend_Application->run() #4 {main} Next exception 'Zend_Controller_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dbt\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dbt\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97) in C:\xampp\htdocs\dbt\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Broker.php on line 336

Comment: and what is the error you found. add it to your question.

Comment: check out accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250697/multiple-sub-query-with-zend-framework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a subquery using Zend DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340564/writing-a-subquery-using-zend-db)

Comment: Incidentally, note that this... `ON p.id in(amanager.scheme_id)`... is the same as this... `ON p.id = amanager.scheme_id`

Comment: @404BrainNotFound: edited my question

Comment: @Strawberry: please check i edited my question the core query is working well on mysql phpmyadmin but when i try to write in zend framework its give me the error which is attached in question